# How to deploy NLP Model on the Cloud

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp

I want to deploy my NLP model on the cloud. How can I access functions and responses of that NLP model in my Python program running in VS Code? Is there any way to connect the Python script which is running on the cloud and the one which is running as usual in VS Code? ( Half Code is on the cloud and Half is on my PC).
main.py file should be on my PC and Other files should be on Cloud.
Is there any way to connect both?

[image]

Comment: How exactly is the NLP model deployed? One standard option is to use HTTP reuqests to communicate between frontend and backend. For this, you require some sort of API that is accessible via HTTP. To implement a python backend, you could use [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/). To send the HTTP request from the frontend, you can use the [Requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.